# Pandas concat using one column of a multindex

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to join in new data that has one value across each value of one column of a multiindex. A basic example is:

```
data = io.StringIO('''Fruit,Color,Count,Price
Apple,Red,3,$1.29
Apple,Green,9,$0.99
Pear,Red,25,$2.59
Pear,Green,26,$2.79
Lime,Green,99,$0.39
''')
df_unindexed = pandas.read_csv(data)
df = df_unindexed.set_index(['Fruit', 'Color'])
df

join = io.StringIO('''Fruit,Count2
Apple,3
Pear,25
Lime,99
''')
join = pandas.read_csv(join)
join = join.set_index(['Fruit'])
join
```

I would like to concat new data using only the fruit column of the index, giving:

```
             Count  Price  Count2
Fruit Color                      
Apple Red        3  $1.29       3
      Green      9  $0.99       3
Pear  Red       25  $2.59      25
      Green     26  $2.79      25
Lime  Green     99  $0.39      99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `on='Fruit'`

You can specify which index level or column to use as the `join` criteria with the `on` argument.

```
df.join(join, on='Fruit')

             Count  Price  Count2
Fruit Color                      
Apple Red        3  $1.29       3
      Green      9  $0.99       3
Pear  Red       25  $2.59      25
      Green     26  $2.79      25
Lime  Green     99  $0.39      99
```

Comment: My pandas doesn't have .join (python3). I tried .merge which seemed similar, but got a keyerror on Fruit.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your pandas should have `join` otherwise it is broken.

Comment: Fails with `KeyError: 'Fruit'`

Comment: First make sure it works with the toy data you provided.  If it doesn't then it is a versioning issue.  If it does but doesn't work for your actual data then it is likely because your actual data doesn't have an index level named `'Fruit'`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html), in last version `.get` should be omit:

```
df['count2'] = df.index.get_level_values('Fruit').map(join['Count2'].get)
print (df)
             Count  Price  count2
Fruit Color                      
Apple Red        3  $1.29       3
      Green      9  $0.99       3
Pear  Red       25  $2.59      25
      Green     26  $2.79      25
Lime  Green     99  $0.39      99
```

If possible multiple columns in `join` use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1).join(join).set_index('Color', append=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reset_index`+`set_index`+`assign`

```
df.reset_index(level=1).assign(count2=join.Count2).set_index('Color',append=True)
Out[1068]: 
             Count  Price  count2
Fruit Color                      
Apple Red        3  $1.29       3
      Green      9  $0.99       3
Pear  Red       25  $2.59      25
      Green     26  $2.79      25
Lime  Green     99  $0.39      99
```